# why is subprocess.popen returning an empty string

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm using python's subprocess.popen to fetch info of a video file.

```
output = Popen('ffmpeg -i "'+avifile+'" -dframes 0 -vframes 0', 
    executable="/bin/bash", stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
    shell=True).communicate()[0]
```

The thing is whenever I run it the output variable is an empty string when I know there should be something. I can manually run ffmpeg fine.

I'm thinking maybe its a problem with the pipes and redirecting I do. Was wondering if someone could fix this up.

Comment: what does `output = Popen(...).communicate()` give you? maybe your getting an error

Comment: there's no error, just nothing.

Comment: Pass a sequence of arguments instead of a string, you will avoid issues with quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd = ['ffmpeg','-i',avifile,'-dframes','0','-vframes', '0']

output = Popen(cmd, 
    #executable="/bin/bash", ive never seen this used ... you may not need it
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
    shell=True).communicate()
```

try that instead maybe ...

Comment: Im getting TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings. avifile is a string variable though.

Comment: what is avifile ? `print avifile,type(avifile)`

Comment: It was the 0 with no quotes. But it still didn't work. The output variable is empty.

Comment: does that command actually output anything ? if you run it in the shell there is output?

Comment: can you copy paste the command and output from the shell into your original question? ... ive gotta goto sleep ... but that will help others answer your question

Answer (score 0):

To read combined stdout/stderr as a string and to get an exception on non-zero return status:

```
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_output as qx

output = qx(['ffmpeg', '-i', avifile] + '-dframes 0 -vframes 0'.split(),
            stderr=STDOUT)
```

Don't use `shell=True` unless you need it.

Comment: ... why `qx`? I think it is a confusing name and I see no reason to change the readable `check_output` with it.

Comment: readability depends on your background. The origin of `qx` (eXecute) are backticks (backward Quotes) *`\`command\``* in bash and corresponding *`qx(command)`* operator in perl.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the variable output to video_output and it worked for some reason. I have absolutely no why.

Comment: My *guess* is that you were overwriting the `output` variable in some way, hence renaming it now the code is not overwriting it anymore. If you had posted a MWE then we wouldn't have lost time speculating but we could have pointed out the real problem.